# How can I remove newline characters at the beginning and ending of a string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am having string as below:

```
var str = "\ncat\n"
```

from the above string i want the output to be

```
str = "cat"
```

Is there any best way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to trim the whitespace characters around the string, with [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), like this

```
console.log("\ncat\n".trim());
// cat
```

You can also remove all the whitespace characters in the beginning and ending of the string using a regular expression, like this

```
console.log("\t\t\t \r\ncat\t\r\n\r".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
// cat
```

The regular expression means that match one or more whitespace characters (`\s` means whitespace characters) at the beginning of the string (`^` means beginning of the string) or at the end of the string (`$` means the end of string). The `+` after `\s` means that match one or more times. The `g` after `/` means global match, it actually makes the RegEx match more than once. So, whenever the match is found, it will be replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [substr function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). In your case, you could do:

```js
var string = '\ncat\n';
document.write(string.substr(1, string.length - 2));
```